# O level Expansion problem.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

yep, title sucks..

```
Q: The expansion of (1+px+qx2)8 = 1+8x+52x2+kx3.
   Find the values of p, q and k.
```

I found the values of $p$ and $q$ and they are:

```
p = 1
q = 3
```

But I am unable to find the value of $k$.

```
ANS: k = 224.
```

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Just expand $(1 + px + qx^2)^8$ to degree $3$.

Comment: You can find tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @anomaly i did xD

Comment: Your work suggest the existence of two formulas for $(a+b)^n$. One is the binomial formula that you used for $a=1$ and $b=px+qx^2$; the other one is the notoriously wrong $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$, which you used for $a=px$ and $b=qx^2$. The rationale for using one over the other appears to be an unspecified judgment call on whether or not you're tired of calculating stuff. Or something as such.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path you were so right, I got the answer now, thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion up to the $x^3$ term gives us the following $$1+8px+28p^2x^2+8qx^2+56p^3x^3+56pqx^3.$$

Now, comparing coefficients with the expression on the right hand side gives $$8p=8,\quad 28+8q=52,$$ which gives $p=1$ and $q=3$. Then, substituting these values to find $k$, we get $$k=56+168=224,$$ as desired.